# Statistic Matlab determine origin from given specifications

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve this problem:
Use the model trained in a) to find the country of origin of a car with 4 cylinders, 1498 cc, 130 HP and a consumption of 0.6 MPG.

I have written in Matlab this trained model with the data set of carsmall in Matlab:

How I can find the origin of the car with the mentioned specifications? I have tried something like this, but there i get en error:

```
Error using classreg.learning.regr.FullRegressionModel.prepareData (line 237)
Invalid data type. Response must be a double or single vector.

Error in classreg.learning.FitTemplate/fit (line 218)
                    this.PrepareData(X,Y,this.BaseFitObjectArgs{:});

Error in fitensemble (line 364)
obj = fit(temp,X,Y);

Error in neu (line 4)
Mdl1 = fitensemble(Tbl,'Origin','LSBoost',100,t);
```

```
Tbl = table(Cylinders,Displacement,Horsepower,MPG,Origin);
t = templateTree('Surrogate','On');
Mdl1 = fitensemble(Tbl,'Origin','LSBoost',100,t);
predMPG = predict(Mdl1,[4 1498 130 0.6])
```

Perhabs someone can give me a tip.

Comment: Why would you train a model for that? First of all, how could these numbers be correlated to country of origin? How do you expect to generalize from this dataset? Second, if you have a complete list of cars, just compare your numbers to known numbers to find the match(es).

Comment: But it is possible to use fitensemble also for non numeric types